# Twitter/Twitter.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, ios4, twitter, ios5

I have done sample on posting tweet messages on iOS 5 and it works great. And I have weak linked the Twitter framework on iOS 5. But when I run the same app on iOS 4.2, it throws me an error like below:

> error: Twitter/Twitter.h: No such file or directory

How can I fix this issue? Please help me out.

Note: On the iOS 5 development machine - I've done sample project using Twitter API and it works fine, and tested on iOS 5 device also. Now trying to get support for iOS4.2, I started working on iOS 4.2 development machine. Now I get the same error:

> error: Twitter/Twitter.h: No such file or directory.

I don't know how to address this error. Since I need to get support for 4.2, I have to work on iOS4.2 development machine. But I'm not able to compile. Please help.

Comment: So your import is "#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>", what is your 'iOS Deployment Target'? Have you also wrapped your 'tweeting' code like so: if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController")) .... or something like that

Comment: bandejapasia : Thanks for the reply and my deplyment target is iOS 4.2

Answer (score 2):

For the SDK, you need to set it at the latest version 5.x.  But for the target, you can set it to 4.2 or whatever version your app will support.  Several options that you can use to check, here is what I have used:

```
#import <Twitter/TWTweetComposeViewController.h>

if ([TWTweetComposeViewController class])
{
   //can tweet
} else
{
   //can't tweet
}
```

Comment: That won't work on iOS less than 5. It will crash. TWTweetComposeViewController won't exist. You need to check using an NSString: if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController")) ... like i did in my answer.

Comment: I have used it on my app that is on app store currently.  It worked with iOS 4.3.  Make sure you set your Base SDK to iOS 5.0 just I posted.

Comment: @bandejapaisa - If building with a base SDK of 4.2 or higher (which is the case when doing this), weak-linking now occurs on a per-class basis: http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis There no longer is a need to use `NSClassFromString()` to determine if a class is present on the older OS version, you can just do what's shown above. You also don't need to explicitly weak link the framework anymore.

Comment: @bandejapaisa - Yeah, I was surprised at that myself when I came across it. It's flown a little under the radar. Apple mentioned it a couple of times at WWDC, but most resources online keep referring to the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController")) {
    [self iOS5Tweet:statusText];
} else .....
```

and

```
- (void) iOS5Tweet:(NSString *)text {
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = [[[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

if (![TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Twitter accounts are set up on this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

[tweet setInitialText:text];
[tweet setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(tweeted:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:result] waitUntilDone:NO];
}];
[self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
```

}

I have iOS Deployment target of 4.2, building with latest SDK (5.0). Deploys and runs fine on both.

Comment: i am currently testing on ios4.2 not ios5

Comment: Yes me too. The app I'm working on runs fine on iOS 4.2. You need to have the base SDK set at 5.0, have you done this?

Comment: I mean , i am trying to build from ios 4.2 which is on my mac not iphone device

Comment: Do you mean you are building for the simulator? Please be more clear exactly what you are doing. You need base SDK to be 5.0. Twitter framework doesn't exist before this. If you want your app to run on devices that are lower than 5.0, then add it as an optional dependency and set deployment target lower.

Comment: Updated and explained the problem ..pls have look on it

Comment: I've read your explanation..... Twitter.h was introduced in iOS5, it doesn't exist on 4.2. You need to upgrade that other machine.... you can't submit to the app store unless you're building using the latest SDK, 5.0. Follow my example and your app will work on a 4.2 device (although it won't support the built in twitter - but then the user won't have iOS 5 anyway). You would need to use a third party API to support twitter on older devices - something like MGTwitter or ShareKit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6035/discussion-between-user198725878-and-bandejapaisa)